add_filter() conflicts with add_action()
My code is likely not great and I'm sure you are all gonna say what the functions do is the wrong way to do it... If so, that is a separate conversation... That is a conversation I would be interested to have; but, for now I just want to understand why the add_filter() is preventing the add_action() from running. When I disable the add_filter() the add_action() runs fine.
function set_milestone_post_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])  && $_GET['post_type']=="milestone") {
        $wp_query->set('meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'pipeline_clause' => array(
                'key'     => 'pipeline',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                ),
            'order_clause' => array(
                'key'     => 'order',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $wp_query->set('orderby', array(
            'pipeline_clause' => 'ASC',
            'order_clause' => 'ASC',
            ),  
        ); 
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_milestone_post_order_in_admin',99 );


function nlqbo_fix_milestone_order()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && $_GET['post_type']=="milestone")
    {
        //Create query of all pipelines
        $query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'pipeline',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key' => 'order',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ));
        
        //Execute query and save to an array 
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $pipelines[]=$post_id;
            //echo $post_id;
            //echo "<br>";
        }
        wp_reset_query();

        foreach($pipelines as $pipeline_id)
        {   
            //Create query of all posts of this post_type
            $query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'milestone',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_key' => array('order'),
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'meta_query'     => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'pipeline',
                        'value'   => $pipeline_id,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ) 
                )
            ));
        
            //Execute query and save to an array 
            $milestones=array(); //Reset for each pipeline
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                $milestones[]=$post_id;
                //echo $post_id;
                //echo "<br>";
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        
            //Update the order to ensure there are no duplicates
            $i=1;
            foreach ($milestones as $milestone_id)
            {
                update_post_meta($milestone_id,"order",$i);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','nlqbo_fix_milestone_order');



For what it’s worth, pre_get_posts isn’t a filter hook, it’s an action hook. You might try fixing that .
